Image doesn't center and border radius does not work as expected
I have been trying to add a border radius to the flag. I am using MUI Typography and React Country Flag

However, I could not get it to work and I don't know why.
Here is my code


import React from "react";
import {Typography} from "@mui/material";
import ReactCountryFlag from "react-country-flag";

function Panel() {
  const flagWrapperStyle = {
    AspectRatio: "4/3",
    overflow: "hidden",
    display: "inline-block",
    borderRadius: "20%",
    width: "24px",
    height: "24px",
    margin: "auto",
    verticalAlign: "middle",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  };

  const flagSizeStyle = {
    width: "24px",
    height: "24px",
    display: "flex",
  };
  return ( 
    <
    Typography gutterBottom variant = "h5"
    component = "div"
    sx = {
      {
        verticalAlign: "middle"
      }
    } >
    Japan <
    Box sx = {
      flagWrapperStyle
    } >
    <
    ReactCountryFlag countryCode = "JP" 
    svg style = {flagSizeStyle}/> 
    </Box> 
    </Typography> 
  )
};
<script src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
<script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.js"></script>



** Not sure how to import react country flag
I played a lot in the browser build-in css editor (F12). But it seems the flag image doesn't center but I am not sure how to fix it. Any help is appreciated.

Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

You’ve given the flags container the border radius but you’ve also made it square (aspect ratio will be ignored when both height and width are set) but the flag isn’t square and it sits at the top of the wrapper. Try giving the wrapper a background color to see what happens.

@Paulie_D Sry to ask you this but do you know how should I import https://github.com/danalloway/react-country-flag this package? Sorry I am new to this and only way i found was to npm install. Not sure where i shd look for the js file to import from HTML.
